# Swift difference between IBOutlet/IBAction and programatically constructing a view?

Tags: swift

im kinda new to swift, and I don't understand what is the difference between the Interface Builder Outlet/Actions and programatically constructing a view. If I have IBOutlet why I don't need to still add them as subviews of the self.view and why do I don't need to instantiate them? As well, to not create two questions, why in the case of a creating a custom UiView I have to load the xib file with Bundle.loadNib?
Thanks,

Comment: I dropped an answer below ? That make sense ?

Comment: Yes thanks, but why do I have to load the loadNib file when creating a custom UiView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot initialize a property that is not nil by nature at instantiation time.
Interface Builder outlet, which always initializes after its owner. In this specific case — assuming it's properly configured in Interface Builder — you've guaranteed that the outlet is non-nil before you use it. That is why we can use as below:

```
 @IBOutlet private var searchBar: UISearchBar!
```

Also, you already added subviews as well.

> SearchViewController - ContentView - searchBar

That means ContentView or self.view is already superview of searchBar so you don`t need to add as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

IBAction, IBOutlet, is responsible for connecting with objects on the Storyboard.
IBOutlet is a variable for accessing values, and IBAction can define an action on the event.
With Storyboard, prototypes can be created quickly and are easy to implement. However, if you work with multiple people, it can cause conflicts, so be careful.